# How does one hide the Response Class in Django REST Swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am trying to hide the Response Class (Model and Model Schema) from API docs I am writing via Django REST Swagger.

I thought maybe I could set `@APIModelProperty(hidden=true)` - but no luck. I can't seem to find anything in the [Django REST Swagger docs](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) either.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the YAML Docstring:
http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml.html

Use the parameter omit_serializer:

```
"""
Method description here
---
omit_serializer: true
"""
```